# Nesting DIV using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to load DIV on button click inside another DIV and on another click it should create a new DIV inside the newly created DIV. Here is my fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/LzCW5/4/ and my code:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="nestDiv()">Generate</a>
<div id='x0'>
    0
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
int level=1;
function nestDiv()
{
    document.getElementById('x'+(level-1)).innerHTML="<div id='x"+level+"'>"+level+"</div>";
    level++;
    if(level==5)
        //do somthing
}
```

I also want to perform some special operation when nesting level reaches 5. I am not so pro at JavaScript. So please tell me how can I achieve this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/LzCW5/7/

Comment: awesome @adeneo. Please add the code as your answer.

Comment: Nah, someone will steal it any minute now and post it, or post something better. If not, you can post it and accept the answer yourself.

Comment: Nice one @adeneo I followed different approach though

Comment: @adeneo can you tell me how using `var` instead of `int` effected the output so much?

Comment: There is no `int` in javascript, only `var` and `const`, so using `int` is a syntax error

Comment: @adeneo oh sorry about that. As I am not so pro in JS. Well thanks for this tip. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you only have to change `int to var` and call the function as a variable:

```
var level=1;
nestDiv = function()
{
    document.getElementById('x'+(level-1)).innerHTML="<div id='x"+level+"'>"+level+"</div>";
    level++;
}
```

[You can see this working here](http://jsfiddle.net/NEOLPAR/763UH/)

Comment: Thanks for pure JS solution. But can you tell me how using `var` instead of `int` effected the output so much?

Comment: Of course, you can see parseInt function here. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to append a `div` in `jQuery`:

```
var newDiv = $("<div id='x"+level+"'>"+level+"</div>");
$('#x'+(level-1)).append(newDiv);
```

This should replace your `document.getElementById...` line

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas78. +1 to you but I marked answer by NEOLPAR, as the solutions given by adeneo and NEOLPAR are in pure JS. :)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding as per your question:

When you click a button, add a div to another div.

Now when the user clicks another button, new div must be added in the previously created new div.

[image]

so let's break it down:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    if($("#referenceDivId").children().length == 0) {
        // if there are no children initially
        $("#referenceDivId").append("<div>New div</div>");
    } else if($("#referenceDivId").children().length == 5) {
        // do your magic when children divs are 5
    }
    else {
        // if it already had children
        $("#referenceDivId").find("div:last").append("<div>New div</div>");   
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/funiy/1/edit)**

Comment: Thanks @mohamedrias. +1 to you but I marked the answer by NEOLPAR, as the solutions given by adeneo and NEOLPAR are in pure JS. :)